# gnome-calculator not displaying number area properly

Tags: gnome-calculator

[image: gnome-calculator screenshot]

On Ubuntu 17.04, the `gnome-calculator` application doesn't show white in the area where numbers go, but instead displays whatever was behind it. How should I go about fixing this? When I add numbers, they just go on top of the number area. Whenever I delete numbers, they stay in place. That makes me think that this is a problem of Calculator just not drawing the background for the number area.

This continues to be a problem in 18.04. The "fix" (or workaround) suggested in the [issue tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-calculator/+bug/1662617) (see comment #7) does nothing. It suggests editing `~/.xinputrc` to read `run_im ibus` instead of `run_im xim` and to log out/in again. This makes no difference on 18.04. A thread [linked in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1620806) has a comment suggesting deleting the `.xinputrc` file "works", but others note that its presence or absence is not the issue, and this is also true in 18.04.

It would be good to know of real fix for this!

---

*Edit:* Interestingly, I've tried older versions of Ubuntu and didn't experience this problem.

*Edit 2:* I also experience this problem when using `gedit`. The text-entry area doesn't display properly.

*Edit 3:* I've recently installed (and began using) another GTK theme. For some bizarre reason, this fixed the problem. However, I'm leaving the question open right now because this isn't a definite fix.

Comment: I found one bug report on this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-calculator/+bug/1662617 perhaps there are more.